# spark-shell, object XXX is not a member of package YYY

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using `spark-shell` to aid my development of a standalone spark program.

When I run my program via `spark-submit` the geohex package is correctly imported.

```
package com.verve.parentchild

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
import net.geohex._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{FloatType, DateType, StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};

object Sessions {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
```

But when I try to import the GeoHex package into the `spark-shell` I get an error

```
➜  spark git:(master) ✗ spark-shell       
16/01/14 07:11:29 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/01/14 07:11:29 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jspooner
16/01/14 07:11:29 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: jspooner
16/01/14 07:11:29 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(jspooner); users with modify permissions: Set(jspooner)
16/01/14 07:11:29 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/01/14 07:11:29 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP class server' on port 55790.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.4.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.0
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jspooner
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: jspooner
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(jspooner); users with modify permissions: Set(jspooner)
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.130:55793]
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 55793.
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/5d/q9yy3dwn2kv6q3xkqqb5dfv80000gp/T/spark-a2b2a7ea-54c8-465f-b9c5-3a7c07571879/blockmgr-61509001-188c-4a31-b417-f593b69753bb
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.1 MB
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /private/var/folders/5d/q9yy3dwn2kv6q3xkqqb5dfv80000gp/T/spark-a2b2a7ea-54c8-465f-b9c5-3a7c07571879/httpd-235c0b35-10d6-4f47-848f-b8c43b52a2bd
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 55794.
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.1.130:4040
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO Executor: Using REPL class URI: http://192.168.1.130:55790
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 55795.
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 55795
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:55795 with 265.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 55795)
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/01/14 07:11:32 INFO SparkILoop: Created spark context..
Spark context available as sc.
16/01/14 07:11:33 INFO HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 0.13.1
16/01/14 07:11:33 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
16/01/14 07:11:33 INFO ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
16/01/14 07:11:33 INFO Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
16/01/14 07:11:33 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
16/01/14 07:11:33 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/01/14 07:11:33 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/01/14 07:11:34 INFO ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
16/01/14 07:11:34 INFO MetaStoreDirectSql: MySQL check failed, assuming we are not on mysql: Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "@" (64), after : "".
16/01/14 07:11:35 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/01/14 07:11:35 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/01/14 07:11:35 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/01/14 07:11:35 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/01/14 07:11:35 INFO ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
16/01/14 07:11:35 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 0.13.1aa
16/01/14 07:11:35 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
16/01/14 07:11:35 INFO HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
16/01/14 07:11:35 INFO HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
16/01/14 07:11:36 INFO SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
16/01/14 07:11:36 INFO SparkILoop: Created sql context (with Hive support)..
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> import net.geohex._
<console>:19: error: object geohex is not a member of package net
       import net.geohex._
                  ^

scala>
```

Tathagata Das in this [article](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/import-org-apache-spark-streaming-twitter-in-Shell-td9665.html) is saying that they separated these non-core functionality into separate subprojects so that their dependencies do not collide/pollute those of of core spark.  His example was a guy trying to import the Twitter stream, but I'm just trying to import a simple geoHex class.

Comment: It's probable that you need to add a `jar` with the library, when you run the shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `--driver-library-path` on your command line when executing the shell as [explained here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

And you can get similar help using `./spark-shell --help`

Comment: Thanks `spark-shell --driver-class-path ./src/main/scala/` is what worked for me.

Comment: So adding the class path gets the import working but doesn't load the GeoHex object. `scala> import net.geohex._
import net.geohex._

scala> GeoHex.encode(40.726, -110.422, 8)
<console>:23: error: not found: value GeoHex
              GeoHex.encode(40.726, -110.422, 8)
              ^
`